# How to solve this problem in Vaadin Table?

Tags: vaadin

I used Vaadin Table component in my application and i set a page length to 15, Length of the Table is not consistent in different screens resolutions . For example in 1440 x 900 resolution height of the table is big but in 1280 x 1024 resolution the height of the table is less . I don't know how to solve this problem.Can any one help me to sort out this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the implementation of Tabsheet and Table component?

Answer (score 2):

Setting pageLength 15 basically says that the table should be just so high that 15 rows can be showed at once. No higher, no lower. Giving a height to the table would override the page length. Are you calling table.setHeight("100%"); or table.setSizeFull()?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can use something like:

```
aTable.setPageLength(0);
aTable.setHeight("100%");
```

Comment: Thanks for ur response, I haven't get any changes with this idea. Actually i am using Table inside the Tab.Is there anything else i need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Both previous answers are correct, while also noting that you probably need to ensure that the tab sheet you are adding *also* has setSizeFull().